# ¿Cómo puedo cubrir los datos que muestra mi URL en DJango?

Tags: python, django, url

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django con visual studio, la verdad soy bastante nuevo y me gustaría saber como puedo cubrir los datos que entrega mi url en Django, básicamente debo entregar un ID de posición a ciertos html y los envió a través del action, se que debo además incluir el dato que envió a través de la url y eso es lo que quiero ocultar, aquí dejo un fragmento de código

```
<td>
    <a type="button" class="" rel="editar" href="{% url 'edicionSistema' s.id %}">
        <img class="icon position" src="{% static 'img/icon/modify.png' %}" />
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a type="button" class="btn-table btn-del" href="{% url 'eliminacionSistema' s.id %}">
        <img class="icon position" src="{% static 'img/icon/delete.png' %}" />
    </a>
```

Ahí se aprecia que envío a través del href el id del sistema para editar o eliminar.

```
path('edicionSistema<int:id>', views.edicionSistema, name="edicionSistema"),
path('editarSistema<int:id>', views.editarSistema, name="editarSistema"),
```

Ahí estoy entregando a mi url el ID para poder trabajarlo en las siguientes paginas, entonces al momento de entrar a la pagina de edición se muestra esta url en el navegador.

[image: URL del navegador]

Quería saber si existe una posibilidad de ocultar eso y diga algo como **`127.0.0.1/editar`** para así no mostrar los datos que se envían, de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Simplemente no lo envíes por url, no uses el método GET, usa POST

Comment: Gracias sinceramente no sabía que enviar los datos por url era GET, tenía una confusión, investigaré sobre como hacerlo con el otro método, muchas gracias